# when i build ffmpeg with cygwin there is an error occurs. How can i solve this?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ndk, cygwin

[image]

**build_android.sh file**

[image]

1. path NDK=C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/android-ndk-r21
2. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please don't post images of code. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your **build_android.sh** file has Windows-style line endings. The easiest way to fix that is to run [dos2unix](http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net) command on the **bash** command line.

Another file to take care of is the **./configure** script. Make sure it is executable, and has Unix-style line endings, too.

When you have fixed all this, you may find that the script still does not work, because at some point it scans the C sources to generate list of modules that should be built. The module names in this list may have the same `\r` character on the end, if the sources have Windows-style line endings.

Don't despair: an easy fix to **./configure** will solve it. Here are the two changes:

```
@@ -3828,1 +3828,1 @@
-    sed -n "s/^[^#]*extern.*$pattern *ff_\([^ ]*\)_$thing;/\1_$out/p" "$file"
+    sed -n "s/^[^#]*extern.*$pattern *ff_\([^ ]*\)_$thing;/\1_$out/p" "$file" | sed 's/\r//'

@@ -3833,1 +3833,1 @@
-    sed -n 's/^extern AVFilter ff_[avfsinkrc]\{2,5\}_\([[:alnum:]_]\{1,\}\);/\1_filter/p' $file
+    sed -n 's/^extern AVFilter ff_[avfsinkrc]\{2,5\}_\([[:alnum:]_]\{1,\}\);/\1_filter/p' $file | sed 's/\r//'
```

Comment: I also run this three commands But, it comes the same error.                                                                            1. dos2unix build_android.sh ,
2. chmod +x build_android.sh ,
3 ./build_android.sh.

Comment: @PradeepSimba can you check that the file is changed (binary) after `dos2unix`? It could be so, that on your system some agent restores the file back to the windows-style line ends; it could be your version control.

Comment: my files end lines not changed. so, how can i solve this?

Comment: **build_android.sh** calls **configure** and, possibly, other scripts. Furthermore, there is a tricky part in **./configure** which searches for all kinds of strings in the source files, and that may generate strings that end with `\r`, and ruin the build. I have updated the answer to reflect these issues.

Comment: You give the two  change. But , where I can this and where I can find this.

Comment: @PradeepSimba just edit your **./configure** accordingly